# Rails mailer and sendgrid with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I am working on adding email functionality to an app I am hosting on heroku.

Here are the relavant files:

## app/mailers/user_actions_mailer.rb

```
def add_user_action(action_params)
        @action_params = action_params
        from = Email.new(email: 'marklocklear@blah.org')
        subject = 'You have been notified'
        to = Email.new(email: 'my_user@gmail.com')
        content = Content.new(type: 'text/html', value: "test")
        mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

        sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'])
        response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
    end
```

This is working fine and I am able to send emails with it. However, my issue is with the 'content' variable above. I want the content to use rails standard mailer template in app/views/user_actions_mailer/add_user_action.html.erb.

I have this file/folder created, but I'm not sure how to point content to this location. I'm tryed not passing content to Mail.new fuction hoping this might trigger rails default mailer wiring, that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to come up with a solution for this, using the [sendgrid-ruby](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby) gem which my example above uses.

I ended up refactoring using THIS PAGE from [sendgrids](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) ruby-on-rails specific documentation.